# Can a Gallio/MbUnit Test be Ran without Installing Gallio?

Tags: deployment, mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net

I've installed TestDriven.Net in Visual Studio 2008 and when I run a mbunit test from TD.Net I get this message:

> It looks like you're trying to execute a Gallio/MbUnit unit test.
>
> For Gallio v3.0.6 build 787 / Gallio v3.1 build 313 or above (recommended):
> Please ensure that the directory containing your 'MbUnit.dll' reference also contains Gallio's
> test runner files ('MbUnit.dll.tdnet', 'TDNet\Gallio.TDNetRunner.dll', 'Gallio.dll' etc.)

Well duh. I haven't installed Gallio yet and that's why it's complaining.

I know that I can easily install Gallio now and get over with it. However, I will really like to find out if I can run these tests without installing Gallio on every single developer's machine. **Can I include a couple of dll's in my bin directory to get this working?**

Has anyone had success with this before?

Note: I have followed the instructions in the message above and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running a brand new version of TDNet that should support running MbUnit tests right out of the box without any installation required.  So that's good.

Try grabbing the ZIP file distribution of Gallio and extracting it somewhere.  You should not need to rearrange the files at all.  Just reference them from your test project in situ.

The minimum set of files that you need to copy to your source tree is a bit complicated because it depends on the features that you want to keep.  Generally it's safe to delete the folders of test framework adapters that you don't want to use right now (RSpec, NUnit, csUnit, etc.) or for plugins that absolutely require installation (VisualStudio, ReSharper).

Just keep in mind that you need to keep the *.plugin files and Resources for all of the plugins that you use.  The dlls are not sufficient on their own.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Gallio, you just need the DLL which is offered via nuget.  Check it out, apply it to your projects, then do a check in on the dll and you're good to go.  They will need a test runner such as TDNet installed though.

1. Open VS2012
2. Select Tools > Library Package Manger > Manage NuGet Packages for solution...
3. Search for "Gallio & MbUnit" & Install (will ask you which open projects you want to apply dll to)
4. Do a SVN check-in on the packages dir and the dll's that are downloaded.